# No provider for ControlContainer Error while using Angular Material Forms with Angular 6

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

I have already written an application using Angular 6 and I am adding Angular material into it.

Reactive forms approach is used in existing application

I have a login module which has below declaration.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
     {path:'login',component:LoginComponent}
    ]),   
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

The Login component has below template - `login.component.html`

```
    <form>
            <mat-form-field>
               <input matInput placeholder="UserName">
            </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

The `AppModule` imports the `LoginModule` into it.

I am getting below console error when `login.html` is rendered

```
compiler.js:1016 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("<section>

        [ERROR ->]<form>
                <mat-form-field>
                   <input matInput placeholder="UserName">
```

This error is resolved when I add `FormsModule` in `LoginModule` as below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
     {path:'login',component:LoginComponent}
    ]),
    FormsModule, //forms module added 
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

Does `FormsModule` needed to be added for Angular material forms to work  ?

But what if we are using reactive forms as the case with my sample application  ?