# Using forms in Ionic throws Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have created an Ionic app with a form. Nothing special (code is below). Before I added a form and used the formgroup and stuff it worked all fine. When I started to add the form group and all things connected I get this error:

> core.js:6260 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NodeInjector:
>   NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer] Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND
>   [ControlContainer]
>       at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:5894)
>       at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:21115)
>       at NodeInjectorFactory.NgControlStatusGroup_Factory [as factory] (forms.js:1073)
>       at getNodeInjectable (core.js:6025)
>       at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:12953)
>       at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:12169)
>       at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:21298)
>       at EditPage_Template (template.html:18)
>       at executeTemplate (core.js:12129)
>       at renderView (core.js:11899)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
>       at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
>       at zone-evergreen.js:860
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41640)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)

I tried the thing that I found online:
Import both Forms Module and ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms in the file app.module.ts

This doesn't work for me and I keep getting the error.

Links I found on SO and tried, but didn't work:

[Getting error suddenly in Angular Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462708/getting-error-suddenly-in-angular-error-nodeinjector-not-found-controlcontain)

[No provider for ControlContainer Error while using Angular Material Forms with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623498/no-provider-for-controlcontainer-error-while-using-angular-material-forms-with-a)

[No provider for ControlContainer and No provider for ControlContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939814/no-provider-for-controlcontainer-and-no-provider-for-controlcontainer)

Here is my code:

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-list inset>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" id="title" type="text"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-input placeholder="Description" formControlName="description" id="description" type="text"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

In my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.page.scss'],
})
export class EditPage {
  editId: number = 0;
  todo : FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.todo = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
    });
  }
}
```

And finally my app.module:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientService } from './core/services/http-client.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports:
    [
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      CommonModule,
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule
    ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    HttpClientService,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Why do you import FormsModule 2x? `import { FormsModule as ngFormsModule, FormsModule , ...`

Comment: You know, I have no idea. I got this piece of code from a working example. I removed it; didn't fix the problem though.

Answer (score 5):

You have to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the page's `module.ts` file.

For example

```js
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { ProfilePage } from './profile.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{path: '', component: ProfilePage}]),
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [ProfilePage]
})
export class ProfilePageModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Modal

Then Import this

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'; //imports

to the parent module of the modal

Comment: This is the correct answer for those using a modal to show a form. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Move the import:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and the NgModule imports:

```
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
```

from `app.module.ts` into `edit.module.ts`.

Answer (score -1):

I've got exactly the same error with formGroup on Ionic5/Angular9.
I've solved this.
You forget to add EditPage on app.module:
`declarations: [AppComponent, EditPage ],
  entryComponents: [EditPage ],`